# TARing relatively

Tags: shell, scripting, tar

I'm writing a script that can tar any given folder and place it in my home/bkp. 
the script will read like this,

```
tar czvf  /home/me/bkp/`basename $1`.tar.gz $1
```

well now, to use it.,

```
backup-script.sh /home/me/folder/sub/to-be-backed-up/
```

Well and good.

Now when I untar it, it creates `home/me/folder/sub/to-be-backed-up/*files*`
I just want `to-be-backed-up/*files*`

Is there any option while creating the tar files that i compress it relatively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-C` option of tar so that it changes to a given directory first.  I often use the trick of appending `/..` to the path to get the parent directory, so that your script would be something like:

```
# backupscript.sh <folder>
tar cvzf /home/me/bkp/`basename $1`.tar.gz -C $1/.. `basename $1`
```

Or you could perhaps use `dirname` instead to change to the right directory first

Comment: In case the filename contains spaces, you should also add double-quotes around the arguments to `tar`, e.g.: `tar cvzf "/home/me/bkp/$(basename "$1").tar.gz" -C "$(dirname "$1")/.." "$(basename "$1")" `